# Answering own question as accepted answer but request deletion

Tags: discussion, flags, accepted-answer, self-answer, not-an-answer

In the 10K tools flags queue I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255323/578411)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772380/578411) answer.

Or a similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197269/578411) which does have another answer.

They both are the sole answers on the OP's own question. The answers basically indicates that the OP couldn't find the delete option for their original post. Initially my idea was to close-vote the question but they doesn't look that bad.

Should those answers be flagged as not answer?
Should a comment to the OP be enough to point out that a question can be deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are indeed posts that deserve "Not An Answer" flags, as they are not attempts at answering the question. All they contain is meta information ("I want this question closed"). I've gone ahead and flagged those as such.

I've commented on the answers to explain what options the OP could have used instead.